# Why does my monthly frequency date range use the last day of the month rather than the first?

Tags: pandas

I am creating a date range as follows:

```
contract_start_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-11-01')
contract_length_months = 3 * 12 # three years

pd.date_range(start=contract_start_date, periods=contract_length_months, freq='M')
>> DatetimeIndex(['2022-11-30', '2022-12-31', '2023-01-31', '2023-02-28',
                  '2023-03-31', '2023-04-30', '2023-05-31', '2023-06-30',
                  '2023-07-31', '2023-08-31', '2023-09-30', '2023-10-31',
                  '2023-11-30', '2023-12-31', '2024-01-31', '2024-02-29',
                  '2024-03-31', '2024-04-30', '2024-05-31', '2024-06-30',
                  '2024-07-31', '2024-08-31', '2024-09-30', '2024-10-31',
                  '2024-11-30', '2024-12-31', '2025-01-31', '2025-02-28',
                  '2025-03-31', '2025-04-30', '2025-05-31', '2025-06-30',
                  '2025-07-31', '2025-08-31', '2025-09-30', '2025-10-31'],
                 dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

My expectation was that the first date in the DatetimeIndex would be `2022-11-01` - why is it instead `2022-11-30`?

Thanks!

Comment: Change `freq = M` to `MS`.

Comment: Thanks @AnoushiravanR - if you add as an answer, I'll accept and upvote!

Comment: You're welcome. No it's not necessary. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `M` means (see [Offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases))

> M month end frequency

You can change `M` to `MS`,

> MS month start frequency

```
pd.date_range(start=contract_start_date, periods=contract_length_months, freq='MS')
```